# Merge Amazon EKS tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

About a half year ago, the tags [eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eks) and [aws-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-eks) was made synonyms to [amazon-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-eks). This has been working very well, as I see it.

Is it time to merge those tags to [amazon-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-eks) ?

> All good tag synonyms should eventually be **merged**

(From [What are merged tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work))